# Adding line segments of equal length in ggplot2 for log-scaled y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the following data

```
x <- c(1, 1.5, 1.8, 2)
y <- 10^x
data <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I wanted to plot log-y vs x and add vertical ticks of equal length centered at y for each x-axis value. I tried using the code below

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.01, 10001),
                   trans = 'log10',
                   expand = c(0, 0)) + 
geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5, y = (10^1.5)-30, xend = 1.5, yend = (10^1.5)+30)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 1.8, y = (10^1.8)-30, xend = 1.8, yend = (10^1.8)+30)) + 
geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = (10^2)-30, xend = 2, yend = (10^2)+30))
```

The resulting image is as below:
[image]

Because of the log scale, two problems were associated with the plot:
(1) the length of vertical ticks above and below the y value point is different, which is most evidently shown when x = 1.5;
(2) total vertical tick length differed by values of x (longest when x = 1.5).

I wish to draw vertical ticks that center at the y value (tick length above and below the point are the same) AND have the same total length (vertical distance between the highest and lowest extreme of a tick) invariant to the x-axis values.

One solution might be do some logarithmic calculations, but I am stuck with that. Perhaps another option is to add vertical line segments in unit of centimeter so that the ticks are of equal length regardless of the y scale. But I do not know what is the appropriate value of cm (except for trial and error approach) and haven't found any function that directly allows for such purpose.

Comment: If you choose a length for half the segment, like 0.5, you can use, e.g., `y = 10^(1.5-.5)` and `yend = 10^(1.5+.5)` for each value.

Comment: @aosmith isn't that basically the same as my answer?

Comment: @dww Yep, very similar. My comment was working off the base-10 notation of the OP to show that the idea still works if one uses a different order of operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
len = 2
data$hi = exp(log(data$y) + len)
data$lo = exp(log(data$y) - len)


ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.01, 10001),trans = 'log10', expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = hi)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = lo))
```

[image]